# How to access local variable declared inside function without use of "return"?

Tags: actionscript-3

This simple example illustrates what's my problem.

I have my function.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var myValue_1;
    var myValue_2;
    var myValue_3;
    var myValue_4;
}
```

And I want to access "myFunction" from outside to bring some variables from it (treating it like a closed container-scope)

my pseudocode:

```
trace(myFunction.myValue_2 + myFunction.myValue_3)
```

is this possible in some simple way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. You need to declare them in the class/global scope, return them or some other way. But there is no way to access those variables from outside the function.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I just wanted to know to stop wasting my time searching for it.